# Prove that the Pitman estimator is itself complete sufficient

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

It's a homework question, but I just have no idea about it ...

Let [image: X_{1} ,... , X_{n}] be random variables according to a distribution having joint density [image: f(x_{1}-\theta ,...,x_{n}-\theta )],where [image: \theta \in R] is a location parameter. Assume that there exists a complete sufficient statistics [image: S(X_{1} ,... , X_{n} )] for [image: theta]. Prove that the Pitman estimator

[image: \delta^{*}(X_{1},...,X_{n})=\frac{\int _{R}\theta f(X_{1}-\theta ,...,X_{n}-\theta) d\theta }{\int _{R} f(X_{1}-\theta ,...,X_{n}-\theta) d\theta }]

is itself complete sufficient.

Comment: Add the self-study tag.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math here.